# Calculating pull-up resistor value for CD4078

Tags: pullup

How can I determine the proper value for a pull-up resistor that's being used as an input to a CD4078 when the [datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/cd4078b.pdf?ts=1593018603797) doesn't mention anything about input impedance?  I'm trying to minimize power usage since my circuit will be powered by a battery.

The datasheet does say that the input current is +- 10mA, so should a 100K @ 5V suffice since that should provide 50mA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering strictly *static* DC operation for these CMOS gates...

Input current at maximum temperature tops-out at one microamp. So a large-value resistor of about 3 MEGohm will ensure a logic high, if no other current paths are present.

So why might you use a smaller-value pullup? A few reasons:

- Noise pulses from nearby traces might momentarily yank a high-resistance pullup low.
- If an open-collector (or open-drain) is to drive this input low, its leakage current would require a smaller-value pullup resistor.
- A large-value pullup resistor pulls up rather slowly in the presence of capacitance. The capacitance of the input alone might be about 7pf. A slow transition time can cause logic gates to go squirrelly, and oscillate as the input slowly transits from low-to-high. A clean logic transition is often required.

The logical solution to these problems is to lower the value of pull-up resistance.
Consider that an input pin that spends most of its time "pulled-up" to logic high causes almost no current drain. You can choose a smaller-value pullup resistor, with almost no down-side.

If the pulled-up input spends most of its time low (pulled down by some other source) then current does flow, and a large-value pull-up resistor value should be chosen to reduce battery drain.

Answer (score 0):

The datasheet states clearly that the maximum input current is 1μA when the input voltage is limited to be not less than 0 and not more than VDD. This is the current value to use when calculating a pullup resistor value.

The 10mA limit applies for any input voltage, and in particular it applies when the input voltage is less than 0 or greater than VDD. In that case the ESD protection diodes at the chip inputs will be forward biased and the current must be limited to prevent damaging those diodes.